# Session cookie is not getting saved from Pantheon

Tags: cookies, setcookie, drupal-9, pantheon

We are working on log in functionality with headless React and Pantheon with REST web services.
When I send login request to Drupal site in localhost, it sets a session cookie in my browser.
However, it doesn't do that for Drupal site deployed to Pantheon.

The cookie:

```
set-cookie: SSESS4ca8b3ff629fc50c99bed7678686=VYfXzM-S18y0n8PylU9HuHBVrEyZezRiwfirxB%2ClL; expires=Fri, 18-Nov-2022 18:14:03 GMT; Max-Age=2000000; path=/; domain=.oursitename.pantheonsite.io; secure; HttpOnly
```

Login request:

```
const body = {
      name: name,
      pass: pass,
    };
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": token,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
    };
    axios
      .post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_DRUPAL_URL}/user/login?_format=json`,
        body,
        config
      )
```

Update:

Cookie is getting stored in Mozilla browser, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append **STYXKEY** to the cookie's name.  Cookies without that prefix are stripped from the request at the edge in Pantheon

You may find interesting as well this official documentation  about pantheon and cookies

https://pantheon.io/docs/cookies

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I still haven't solved the issue. I'm quite new to Drupal, so it's not very clear to me where would the function for rewriting a cookie go in a freshly installed Drupal-Pantheon site? Would it go to settings.php?

Comment: Did you try changing your cookie name? Did you debug it to make sure it was changed?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where the cookie is getting set. It's a default session cookie that Drupal sends when a user is logged in. Also, wouldn't it be part of a core? As I understand I shouldn't be rewriting core.